# I don't know how to sync contacts between my phonebook on Samsung Galaxy Europa i5500 and Gmail?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, samsung-europa

I am the new one with android samsung-europa, and I need help. All my options for syncing with Gmail acc. and my phonebook on my Europa are checked. But it doesn't seem to sync them. I did it manually ( copied contacts on SD card then copied them to my PC and then uploaded them to gmail). But later, as I am adding my new contacts (on my Phone, or SIM, or Gmail) it doesn't sync them :( . Do I need to download some application to force syncing or what???